# Assign a value when for integer when USE select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

This question is relevant to SQL Server. I have table with column called `gender` and 1 or 0 will be saved as integer. I want to know whether there is a method assign a label when I selecting it using `SELECT` statement.

For example

```
SELECT gender 
FROM emp
```

AND if 1 occur `Male` AND 0 occur `Female` should be displayed.

Comment: `SELECT CASE gender WHEN 1 THEN 'Male' WHEN 0 THEN 'Female' END`

Comment: Interesting that you chose to use Integer rather than BIT or CHAR(1).

Comment: I just wanted the way of selecting rather the data type. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the CASE operator, i.e. CASE gender when 1 then 'Male' else 'Female' end.
Full select as follows:

```
 SELECT  gender, 
         CASE gender 
           when 1 then 'Male' 
           else 'Female' 
         end as gender_name    
 FROM emp
```

**UPD:**
Option with N/A to process all possible optios (if gender field value not in range [0,1], but I prefer to use check constraint to determine possible values, to avoid weird/unexpected values):

```
 SELECT  gender, 
         CASE 
           gender 
             when 1 then 'Male' 
             when 0 then 'Female' 
             else 'N/A' 
         end as gender_name    
 FROM emp
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You save the day for me

Comment: I also suggest you to take @SaagarEliasJacky answer bellow into consideration, just in case use a default value and return 'N/A' or something else (instead of use Female for all non-1 cases) to cover all possible cases. I prefer to limit field value on the DB level, but I don't know, what values your gender field accepts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN gender = 1 THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END AS gender
FROM emp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE...WHEN...THEN...END` for this

```
select case when GENDER = 1 then 'Male'
            when GENDER = 0 then 'Female'
            else 'N/A'
       end as GENDER
from emp;
```

Find more about this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)